# Convert timestamp to DATE format (MM-DD-YYYY) using postgers sql

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a function written in postgres sql.
The function is returning value using return table.
The table value from where I'm fetching the data is timestamp but while returning I need to convert the timestamp to date format like MM-DD-YYYY while fetching the records.
Table should have only date as value

`RETURNS TABLE(employee_id character varying,  effective_date timestamp )`

`BEFORE 2020-05-08 00:00:00`

`AFTER 05-082020`

It would be helpful if anyone can guide me to return the value in date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the result of the function in your select statement where you use it:

```
select employee_id, 
       to_char(effective_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as formatted_date
from your_function();
```

Alternatively if you need a real "date" rather then a string, you can cast the result:

```
select employee_id, 
       effective_date::date as effective_date
from your_function();
```

If you **always** do that, you can do the casting inside your function, rather then i the query using the function.

Comment: Obviously `date` if you want a date